# best technique to erase from std::map multiple keys

Tags: c++, sqlite, dictionary, std

Need to erase from `std::map<unsigned int, SomeNullPointer*>` some multiple keys.

Before that operation we receive the keys from sqlite database and store them at other `std::map`, or `std::list` or any other `std` container.

We are not allowed to `erase` them immediately after receiving from database, because there is unwanted BUSY time for database while `SELECT` executed and additional locked time for mutex of first `map` with keys.

So, suggest the best technique to erase keys from one `map`(or other container) at another `map`

Comment: `SomeNullPointer*`sounds like a very interesting type...

Comment: @anderas it's `simplification` for question. :)

Comment: So, the good idea to start from the point of what container to use for `temporary` keys...

Comment: How are you *currently* doing this? Post *that* please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can store temporary keys in a `std::vector<unsigned int>`, because they are to be used purely as sequential data.

After receiving all keys from database and stored them in a `std::vector<unsigned int>`, iterate through it and erase them from your `std::map<unsigned int, SomeNullPointer*>`.

Like:

```
std::map<unsigned int, SomeNullPointer*> data;
// suppose you have many data
std::vector<unsigned int> tempKeys;
// receive keys from database...
// make sure you have received all the keys from database,
// maybe after some signal sent from database?
```

Then you do

```
for (auto key : tempKeys)
{
    data.erase(key);
}
```

or maybe your pointer needs to be deleted:

```
for (auto key : tempKeys)
{
    auto it = data.find(key);
    delete (it->second);
    data.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: +1 first extract from sqlite the complete output in a very simple vector, terminate the statement thus freeing your db (commit the transaction if needed) and then lock your map, iterate through the vector of keys and delete one by one. Then unlock. Maps are fast.